# Bottlepy - How to access bottle arguments {{var}} from javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, bottle

I'm developing a template that will be included into a larger template, and for some reason the template is not accepting any arguments in Javascript.

Everything is fine if the argument is accessed from the html. Here's an example:

```
test.tpl: 

<p>from html: {{arg}}</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.alert("from script "+{{arg}});
</script>
```

From another template, I include test.tpl and pass it with a arg value:

```
main.tpl:

% include('test.tpl', arg='some value')
```

The end result is that, the argument in html is displayed fine:

```
from html: some value
```

But the windows alert gives something weird:

```
[object HTMLLIElement]
```

What is going on?

Comment: i think you need to quote the JS literal. but `"abc" +some value` should be a syntax error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dandavis pointed out in the comment, the proper way to reference the argument in javascript is to put it in a quote:

```
test.tpl: 

<p>from html: {{arg}}</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.alert("from script "+"{{arg}}");
</script>
```

Output:

```
from script some value
```

Without the quotation mark, what JavaScript actually sees is a string followed by a variable called *some value*, which is not cannot be concatenated with a string literal. This is how my original code looks like to the browser:

```
    window.alert("from script " + some value);
```

which is wrong.