# Bottlepy - Access bottle arguments/Tuples {{var}} from javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, arguments, bottle

I develop an application at home and have a problem and I am not able to find a solution. Maybe because I'm a beginner at this topic.

I want to use bottle arguments especially a tuple in my JavaScript to create buttons.
I'm able to access one value of the tuple with this function. It works fine:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    text += "The value is " + "{{data[1]}}" + "<br>";
    }
```

I found this solution on: [Bottlepy - How to access bottle arguments {{var}} from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501534/bottlepy-how-to-access-bottle-arguments-var-from-javascript)

The problem is that I want to get not every time "the first" value. I am searching for something like this (I want to use i instead of 1):

```
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    text += "The value is " + "{{data[i]}}" + "<br>";
    }
```

I hope everybody understands the problem and anybody can help me. The script should be only an example.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is in my HTML template I assign variables in a script tag PRIOR to loading the javascript.  Then my js script has access to those variables inside the JS without having to template the JS at all.

index.tpl that I call via a bottle template. `template('index.tpl, urls=urls)`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var websocketServerLocation = '{{urls['websockurl']}}'
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/common/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/common/js/reconnecting-websocket.min.js"></script>
```